# Creating an image in PHP using a MySQL resut set

Tags: php, mysql, gd

Is there any way to create an image out of MySQL result set in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) using [GD Graphics Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library)?

I am ucrrently displaying the resultset in a table format in my PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and convert your HTML generated result data as a pdf using [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) (it does have some basic HTML support). AFAIK there's no library that renders HTML and converts to an image at the same time.

If you HAVE to have an image instead, consider using GDs built in methods to render your data ... though this might be a PITA.

Good luck.

Comment: Agreed, GC Library would be nice to render data in (if done correctly).

Comment: Actually, weak GD with it's few formats supported is worst choice :)
take a look to imagemagick

Comment: GD may be worse but it's available with even the crappiest hosts.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way while displaying current resultset. Basic HTML knowledge is needed to use PHP.

Storing images in the disk directory instead of database is much easier to use and more reliable.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the OP's question. He wants to generate an image out of a database result set.

Comment: Ah, may be. 
Well, not GD nor any other graphic library would help
Because it's an HTML render engine what does he need in this case.